# Jasmine - ways of stubbing URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have the following line in my code:

```
var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Unfortunately phantomjs doesn't have URL so I need to stub it out in Jasmine, but not sure how.

I am using Jasmine 2 and AngularJS 1.4

Comment: Please add with controller and jasmine tried script

Answer (score 3):

```
spyOn(URL, 'createObjectURL').and.returnValue("something");
```

This assumes URL is accessible in your unit tests.
Alternatively, another approach, is to define URL in your unit tests as ...

```
var URL = {
    createObjectURL: function() { return "something" }
}
```